# Weird PHP number issue

Tags: php, if-statement, numbers

Here is the simple code:

```
$result = 0;
$result = $obj->delete($this_id);
echo "Result:" . $result;
var_dump($result);
if ( (int) $result < 0 || $result == null ) {
   echo "Here" . $result;
       var_dump($result);exit;  
}
```

Here is the result:

```
Result:0int(0)
Here0int(0)
```

Its not supposed to enter into `if` block. Because $result is `=` 0. Not `<` 0.

Am I missing something or PHP handles this differently?

Comment: use === and see if that works

Comment: I want to check if the number is less than 0. How to use ===?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comparison to null should be `===` instead of `==`. Since null can evalulate to 0, the comparision evaluates (0 == null) = true

```
if ( (int) $result < 0 || $result === null ) {
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php for more information

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the cast to an int type is making your variable test incorrectly against 0.

Replace `if( (int) $result ...` with `if( $result ...`

Comment: It was like that before. I added casting to see if it makes any difference. No change with or without casting.

Answer (score 0):

Its not the first validation which matches:

```
var_dump(0 == null); //true
var_dump(false == null); //true
```